# Calling External API in next JS

Tags: next.js, laravel-passport

How to call external api in next js ?

I keep receiving error Request failed with status code 500',

Basically what I am trying to achieve is this . Once page is redirected back with query parameters, I want to fetch an external api.

This is what I did in

pages/callback/index.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import axios from "axios";



const index = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.query.code) {
      axios
        .post("/api/token", {
          code: router.query.code,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);//getting error 500 here
        });
    }
  }, [router.query]);

  return <div>Your Passport callback page</div>;
};

export default index;
```

pages/api/token.js

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { code } = req.body;
    const data = {
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URL,
      code,
    };
    const pos = await axios.post("http://localhost:5001/oauth/token", data); //calling external api here
    res.json({ message: "Hello there", pos });
  }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Someone please help thank you

Comment: Would be helpful if you added a bit more information. First, at what point in this process are you getting the error, `Request failed with status code 500`? Is it during the redirect or before/after the API. What is the code you use to fetch an external API?